# Why do we print variable values like this?

Tags: java

I want to know why we concatenate a dummy string with a variable while printing its value.

Eg.

```
system.out.print(var + " ");
```

Comment: No we don't necessarily do that.

Comment: Oh, thank you! @Gautam

Comment: Can you share somemore context? On its own, this line doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: Because the person wanted a space between the value of the var and the next printed value, most probably.

Comment: @Mureinik int a=1; system.out.prijnt(a+" ");

Comment: Sounds like this is probably part of a loop that prints a bunch of things separated by spaces (and also probably prints an extra space on the end that it ideally shouldn't).

Comment: @JBNizet Alright! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation with an empty string is a technique *some* developers use to convert any value to a string. It's unnecessary with `System.out.print` as that accepts any value anyway. I prefer using `String.valueOf` anyway:

```
String text = String.valueOf(variable);
```

This is clearer in terms of the purpose being converting a value to a string, rather than concatenation.

However, in the case you've given, it's possible that the developer wasn't just using concatenation for that purpose - but actually to get the extra space. For example:

```
int var1 = 1, var2 = 2, var3 = 3;
System.out.print(var1 + " ");
System.out.print(var2 + " ");
System.out.print(var3 + " ");
```

Those will all print on the same line:

```
1 2 3
```

Other options include:

- Using a `StringBuilder` to build up the string before printing it
- Putting it all into a single `System.out.print` call: `System.out.print(var1 + " " + var2 + " "  + var3);`
- Using `printf` instead: `System.out.printf("%d %d %d", var1, var2, var3);`

Comment: Wonderful. That example really made it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely sorry. The question was l1.setText(var+" "); and it is done because a text field cannot take an integer value, so we concatenate a dummy string at the end of it, so the integer value in var can be printed.

Thank you all for helping me out!